# Is it OK to add @Id to an entity which mapped to a table without Primary key column in Spring boot Jpa?

Tags: java, oracle11g, spring-data-jpa, database-sequence

I've started working on a legacy oracle database and using Spring boot Jpa trying to insert a new row in a table (`CHANNELMGR_REQUEST`) without Identity:

[image]

This table has a Numeric column (`CM_ISN`) and logically could be an Identity candidate, but I could not touch the database for some reason.

I found an existing sequence (`CHANNELMGR_SEQ`) that is used for generating value for that `CM_ISN` column too.

[image]

So I decided to use that sequence and added some annotation in my equivalent POJO as follow and mapped to the sequence to that `CM_ISN` column. But not touching the database :

[image]

My repository is like this :

[image]

While inserting the row, sucessfully invoke the sequence but get exception as bellow :

[image]

My questions :

1. Is it wrong to modify an entity and add @Id to that which is not in in equivalent table?
2. What's wrong with my code that i get error?

PS: I'm sorry for putting images instead of actual source codes, The reason is because development machine has no access to the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's wrong if it is not the primary key
2. Use BigDecimal instead of Number

Comment: BigDecimal solved the problem. Why the first question is wrong? what do you suggest instead?

Comment: By using @Id, you rely on the column to be unique, which is not enforced by the database even if it is logically unique and non-null. 
That might lead to very unexpected results when data gets inserted that doesn't fit the requirements of your annotation.